# Dvd ezmaker 7 driver compiling issue

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm unsuccessful with compilation dvd ezmaker 7 driver under raspbian (kernel 3.2.0-4-rpi), although it is successfully compiled under same Debian (kernel 3.2.0-4-686-pae). So, I've done following steps on Raspbian:

- install 3.2.0-4 kernel (aptitude install linux-image-3.2.0-4.rpi)
- install 3.2.0-4 headers (aptitude install linux-headers-3.2.0-4.rpi)
- install linux source (linux-source-3.2 - some dvb-core header files are needed for compilation)
- download driver source (v. 1.0.28)

and try to compile (with make command) it without any success: gcc says "cx231xx-i2c: error: implicit declaration of function 'i2c_master_recv' " (and same for 'i2c_add_adapter' and 'i2c_del_adapter').

But, all these functions are defined in /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-rpi/source/include/linux/i2c.h:

```
extern int i2c_master_recv (const struct i2c_client *client, char *buf, int count);
extern int i2c_add_adapter (struct i2c_adapter *);
extern int i2c_del_adapter (struct i2c_adapter *);
```

and there is the #include  directive in cx231xx-i2c.c file.

Problem i2c_del_adapter usage for example:

cx231xx-i2c.c

```
int cx231xx_i2c_unregister(struct cx231xx_i2c *bus)
{
    i2c_del_adapter(&bus->i2c_adap);
    return 0;
}
```

and cx231xx.h (struct cx231xx_i2c definition)

```
struct cx231xx_i2c {

struct cx231xx *dev;


int nr;


/* i2c i/o */

struct i2c_adapter i2c_adap;

struct i2c_algo_bit_data i2c_algo;

struct i2c_client i2c_client;

u32 i2c_rc;


/* different settings for each bus */

u8 i2c_period;

u8 i2c_nostop;

u8 i2c_reserve;

};
```

I don't familiar to C and gcc, and cannot understand why gcc considers these functions as undefinded (besides, there is no problem with compilation under Debian).